# Activate Application Window on clicking dock icon

Tags: macos, mac

I would simply like to activate Application Window when clicking on the dock icon.
Currently you must hold the icon to activate the functionality I would it to automatically occur just like Ubuntu's when making the 2nd click.

Please refer me to a different site if this should be posted elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an AppleScript that does such by assigning the appropriate keyboard preference in System Preferences.

Then an AppleScript icon to the dock like the following.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set frontmostProcess to first process where it is frontmost
    set visible of frontmostProcess to false
    key code 61
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. Expose is built in to the core of OS X. You cannot replace it, but you can turn it off in the System Preferences. As far as I know there is no third party Expose for OS X.

Ubuntu is probably using a similar version of expose used in earlier versions of OS X. Most operating systems implemented such a thing a few years after the first time OS X was published with that functionality. It changed over the years (and is now mostly taken over by Mission Control), but the ones used in other operating systems might not have taken the same path.

Comment: I would like to activate expose "Application Windows" when clicking on icon on the dock.

Comment: I think that is already built in. I have not used it for a while because I mainly use keyboard shortcuts, but I think you can do this by simply holding the mouse on an icon. It will do Application Expose on that icon for you. I'll have a peek at the Help documentation, Apple usually documents this stuff pretty good.

Comment: Ok I would like it to activate with a single click with the application is already focused like ubuntu.

Comment: It appears this functionality was changed in OS X 10.6. You have a few remaining options: You can use a hotkey to activate Application Expose. This allows you to push a button to expose the current application. You can set it from System Preferences -> Mission Control. Mouse buttons can be used too. Different option: use gestures. This is possible when using a trackpad or mouse with touch surface or touchscreen. Set in System Prefs->Trackpad. Third option: right-click the app and use "Show all Windows". This can be done in 1 move: hold the right mouse button, slide & release on the menu item.